# Determine the startposition for Perlin worms

Tags: procedural-generation, random, perlin-noise

I want to implement Perlin worms for the level generation of my 2D game and I was wondering, which options exist to find the startposition for the worms.

My idea was to randomly start zero to X (constant) worms per chunk and use random x and y coordinates for each worm. Are there other options I could try and compare to my idea?

Comment: This question looks similar to a [previous Q&A about Perlin worms & related cave generation techniques](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53400/39518)

Answer (score -1):

One other way, if you are looking for a natural look to the level (cave) you could use [cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). It is very easy and flexible to code and it works well when properly coded.